# Spacing a TableLayout from the top of a screen

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am currently trying to fix my UI to incorporate a background image. My current display has 8 buttons in a LinearLayout stacked vertically on top of one another. I would like to change this to a 3x3 grid with 1 button missing, but space it from the top of the screen.

The reason I would like to space it from the top of the screen is that there is text in the image That acts as a title. This is an example of how my layout looks now...

[image]

The title runs behind the top two buttons. There are also graphics along the bottom of the screen which I would like to keep free.

This is what I would like to replicate ( sorry for the crappy quality I made it in MS Paint )

[image]

The `Blah Blah Blah` and scribble on the bottom are both part of the background image so they are not represented in the XML file. The ONLY things in my XML file would need to be the buttons, and an appropriate layout to hold them. Does anyone know how to create this spacing above/below a layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work, nest it inside your existing layout or make it the parent and adjust the top LL's margin and background to suit your needs:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_margin="30dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:baselineAligned="false" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:baselineAligned="false" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:baselineAligned="false" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty easy to make it. Play around with LinearLayout and layout_weight attribute. I have pasted a sample code below that gives me 3x2 view. You can change as per your needs.

```
    <ScrollView
        style="@style/Fill"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="6dip" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/home_btn_feature1"
                    style="@style/HomeButton"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_button1"
                    android:onClick="onClick"
                    android:text="@string/title_feature1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/home_btn_feature2"
                    style="@style/HomeButton"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_button2"
                    android:onClick="onClick"
                    android:text="@string/title_feature2" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/home_btn_feature3"
                    style="@style/HomeButton"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_button3"
                    android:onClick="onClick"
                    android:text="@string/title_feature3" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/home_btn_feature4"
                    style="@style/HomeButton"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_button4"
                    android:onClick="onClick"
                    android:text="@string/title_feature4" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/home_btn_feature5"
                    style="@style/HomeButton"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_button5"
                    android:onClick="onClick"
                    android:text="@string/title_feature5" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/home_btn_feature6"
                    style="@style/HomeButton"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_button6"
                    android:onClick="onClick"
                    android:text="@string/title_feature6" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```